# Replace a string from lookuptable in R

Tags: r

I have a txt file with a list:

```
name
Test_123
run_456
Test_789
```

I have another lookuptable that contains the "ID" and gives me a "Plate"

```
ID  plate
123 xxx
456 zzz
789 bbb
```

Would love to get here

```
Test_xxx
run_zzz
Test_bbb
```

My current code does not work entirely.
Either getting `<NA>`  as I guess it looks for values and not for a string or errors.

Thanks so much for your help!
 B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tidyverse` way to do this would be:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  separate(name, c("name", "ID"), convert=TRUE) %>%
  left_join(df2, by="ID") %>%
  mutate(new_name = paste(name, plate, sep="_"))
```

Using:

```
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("Test_123", "run_456", "Test_789")),
                 .Names = "name", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(123L, 456L, 789L), plate = c("xxx", "zzz", 
                                                          "bbb")), .Names = c("ID", "plate"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                  -3L))
```

Note that:

- `separate(..., convert=TRUE)` use some heuristics to convert character into integer. You can otherwise do this manually: `mutate(ID=as.integer(ID))`
- You could use `unite()` (which does the opposite of `separate()`) instead of `mutate(new_name = paste(name, plate, sep="_"))`, which would also remove the previous columns

Answer (score 0):

An option would be `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("(\\d+)", setNames(as.list(df2$plate), df2$ID), df1$name)
#[1] "Test_xxx" "run_zzz"  "Test_bbb"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("Test_123", "run_456", "Test_789")),
  .Names = "name", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(123L, 456L, 789L), plate = c("xxx", "zzz", 
"bbb")), .Names = c("ID", "plate"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Hi akrun. thanks as well. I get this error: Error: is.character(x) is not TRUE would be great to have a very short command for it.

Comment: @Dennis If you check the data I used, the columns are `character` class.  Use `as.character(df1$name)`  and change `df2` columns as well if they are `factor`

Comment: I have another set in which I have to replace only the string in the middle but want to keep the end part of the name e.g. Test_xxx_.abc would it be possitble to ass some spaceholders for the gsub string?

Comment: @Dennis Are you looking to replace the 'abc' at the end. then use `gsubfn("(\\w+)$",`  Here, the `setNames` condition should be changed accordingly based on the new data

Comment: that worked nice. now only the replaced strings are missing. Your solution would give me the 100% for any scenario that I plan in the future.

Comment: @Dennis Sorry, you need to provide some reproducible example to match the pattern.  In the example code you provided in the post, it works as we can test it

Comment: STA_298576_S1_.gf is the file name the string 298576 in this case should be replaced with KD23 and so on. sorry for the inconvenience in this case.

Comment: @Dennis I would guess the original pattern would work here `gsubfn("(\\d+)", setNames(as.list(df2$plate), df2$ID), df1$name)` where the df2$ID would be the numeric part and df2$plate would be replacement

Comment: with the first string the result is: STA_1_S1_.gf for the example file. with gsubfn("(\\w+)$" the output is: STA_298576_S1_.gf

Comment: Try `gsubfn("(\\d+)", setNames(as.list("KD23"), "298576"), "STA_298576_S1_.gf")#
[1] "STA_KD23_S1_.gf"`  The replacement part can be a named list (sort of like a dictionary)

Comment: @Dennis What I meant is `lst <- setNames(list("KD23", "KD24"), c(298576, 298577));
 gsubfn("(\\d+)", lst, "STA_298576_S1_.gf")#
[1] "STA_KD23_S1_.gf"`

Answer (score 0):

For a base R option, you could add a new column to your first data frame with the exact join data:

```
df1$ID <- sub(".*_(?=[0-9]+)", "", df1$name, perl=TRUE)
df1$start <- sub("_[0-9]+", "", df1$name)
```

Then, use `merge`:

```
result <- merge(df1, df2, by="ID")
```

And finally create your desired output column:

```
result$out <- paste0(result$start, "_", result$plate)
result$out

[1] "Test_xxx" "run_zzz"  "Test_bbb"
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- data.frame(name=c("Test_123", "run_456", "Test_789"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(ID=c("123", "456", "789"),
                  plate=c("xxx", "zzz", "bbb"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

### Demo

Comment: df1$ID <- sub(".*_(?=[0-9]+)", "", df1$name) this gave me this error Error in sub(".*_(?=[0-9]+)", "", filelist$names) : 
  invalid regular expression '.*_(?=[0-9]+)', reason 'Invalid regexp'

Comment: @Dennis Sorry, we need to use the `perl=TRUE` mode in that first call to `sub`.  My demo already had this, but the code I pasted here was a few versions behind.

Comment: Hi Tim. merging gave me as well an error - its empty: Col names + <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Comment: @Dennis Then there must be an issue with your data; the demo works fine.